# How to change color of fontawesome icon by hovering mouse inside anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I'm facing problem in navbar, Inside there I've put Resume link and icon to download resume, in the styling if I hover over RESUME then only RESUME getting color icon doesn't change it's color, but if we hover to the icon then and only then it changes it's color

Here's my react code

```
function Navbar() {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Sahil</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} style={{ color: "#000", }} />
                </button>
                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#About">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#Project">Project</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item ">
                            <a className="nav-link text-white" href="../Sahil_Resume.pdf" download={"SahilResume"}>
                                Resume <FontAwesomeIcon className='resume' icon={faDownload} style={{color: "#000",}} />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a className="nav-link text-white" href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

this is css I applied in it

```
.navbar{
  background-color: var(--secondaryColor) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px -10px 20px 0px black;
}

.navbar-brand{
  color: var(--primaryDefColor) !important;
}
.navbar-brand:hover{
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-link {
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  color: var(--primaryDefColor) !important;
}

.resume:hover{
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: border-bottom, color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I'm expecting that when someone hover over resume link then icon also change it's color

Answer (score 0):

The .resume class is applied to the FontAwesomeIcon component, but the hover effect is being applied to the .resume:hover selector, which might not be specific enough.

```
.nav-item:hover .resume {
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**"This rule targets the .resume class specifically when its parent .nav-item is being hovered over."**

Answer (score 0):

Add className "resume" on li

```
 <li className="nav-item resume">
   <a className="nav-link text-white" href="../Sahil_Resume.pdf" download={"SahilResume"}>  
     Resume <FontAwesomeIcon className='resume' icon={faDownload} style={{color: "#000",}} />
   </a>
 </li>
```

Also, change the css to this

```
.nav-item.resume:hover .nav-link,
.nav-item.resume:hover .resume {
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: var(--primaryColor) !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--primaryColor) !important;
  transition: border-bottom, color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```